# Is it possible to abstract the Link declarations when using React-Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-component, react-router-component

Consider the following:

```
import { Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

function Index() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}

function NotFound() {
  return <h2>Not found</h2>;
}

function App() {
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Next.js!</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about/">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/users/">Users</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/people/">People</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Index} />
        <Route path="/about/" component={About} />
        <Route path="/users/" component={Users} />
        <Redirect from="/people/" to="/users/" />
        <Route component={NotFound}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Is there anything that prevents one from doing this?

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import LinkNav from './LinkNav'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

function Index() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}

function NotFound() {
  return <h2>Not found</h2>;
}

function App() {
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Next.js!</h1>
      <nav>
        <LinkNav/>
      </nav>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Index} />
        <Route path="/about/" component={About} />
        <Route path="/users/" component={Users} />
        <Redirect from="/people/" to="/users/" />
        <Route component={NotFound}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Are there any drawbacks?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. I do this all the time. What is your concern if I may ask?

Comment: @euvs Only asking because I am working with Next.js and having a terrible time figuring out using `Semantic-UI-React` menu item with Next's `Link` component. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653701/imperative-version-of-next-router-not-working-with-semantic-ui-reacthttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653701/imperative-version-of-next-router-not-working-with-semantic-ui-react

So i'm thinking of using https://github.com/toomuchdesign/next-react-router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use  `import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'`
instead of  `import { Redirect } from 'react-router'`,

as  `'react-router-dom'`  is a wrapper on top of 'react-router' and you are already used 
 `'react-router-dom'`  in your codebase

- Are there any drawbacks?

You have created a component but it's not fully data driven (if you required to). You may refactor your code to feed your LinkNav

App.js

```
function App() {
  const navBars = [
    { name: "Home", path: "/" },
    { name: "About", path: "/about" },
    { name: "Users", path: "/users" },
    { name: "People", path: "/people" }
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>welcome</h1>
      <nav>
        <LinkNav data={navBars} />
      </nav>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Index} />
        <Route path="/about/" component={About} />
        <Route path="/users/" component={Users} />
        <Redirect from="/people/" to="/users/" />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

linkNav.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const LinkNav = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(nav => (
        <li key={nav.path}>
          <Link to={nav.path}>{nav.name}</Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default LinkNav;
```

Comment: I wound up reorganizing my nav to be commensurate with your answer! Thank you Tareq!! Side question if I may; Should a nav component like you have illustrated only handle `active` states and `paths`? I'd like to have the links respond to changes in my redux store. For example show or hide a link depending on if a user is logged in? In other words is making a component do too many things a anti-pattern?

Comment: I think you may pass the data as props for those you want to show only in LinkNav, it shouldn't effect your LinkNav code

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how I always do to create a Navbar. `<Link>` is just like a normal `<a>` tag, except that it pushes the URL to the history stack, rather than making a request to the server like the `<a>` tag does.